# Thunderbird - watch or ignore threads

Tags: thunderbird, threads

If I go to View->Threads I can select to view only watched threads, or to display ignored threads.

How do I set this on a thread? I keep searching, but there just doesn't seem to be any option to mark a thread watched/ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only watch/Ignore News threads, not ordinary email, or RSS feeds.

When viewing a news message, these options are under the "Message" menu. "Ignore Thread" (K) and "Watch Thread" (W) are at the end of the menu.

[image]

Comment: Note that TB24 has added this now for ordinary email as well...

Answer (score 1):

This is old but still comes up in searches so it's worth updating.  As Brett Zamir points out in his comment, TB24 added this for email messages.

It is set (toggled actually) on the selected message by pressing the W key on your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a scoping problem augmented by a language problem.

- The scoping problem is that it should only be visible to news threads, and not to any messages or other types of thread.
- The language problem is that you should really call it a "follow" option.

You also need a "watch" option which alerts the user if there's a reply to a particular message. Similarly, there's no point in telling us we've got mail,the user who hasn't really has mastered their span defences.